# QGIS Georeferencer points file saving projection data

Tags: qgis, point, georeferencing

After georeferencing .points file shows some unnecessary data like CRS data and some other, I want that after georeferencing points file keeps only points coordinate data. Is there any chance to manually change this in the current version of QGIS? Otherwise I will have to downgrade to version 3.16. I actually need QGIS to save points file without the data that is highlighted in blue.

[image]

Comment: What version of QGIS are you using?

Comment: Instead of downgrading, wouldn't it be better to delete all the text before "mapX" with a script?

Answer (score 0):

I was using latest Long Term Version 3.28.9 and downgraded to 3.16.0

I don't know what script to use to bulky delete these texts, and it was easier to downgrade as I have to georeference more than 100 maps.